# How to display options on Magento 2 associated products page if they display individually in catalog page

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, associate-products

In magento 2 `catalog page` all configurable products are listed along with associated products(I changed the `Not visible individually` to `Catalog,Search`).Now when clicking on the associated products(Simple product) I want to display the options available with the parent product( Configurable Product)